# How to get the exact year,month,date between two dates in one column oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get the exact year,month,date between two dates in one column oracle sql

Below is my query ,currently my output is showing as 0 Years 11 Months 30 Days but i need output like 1 Years 0 Months 0 Days

```
select trunc(months_between(lease.lease_end_date,(lease.lease_start_date)) / 12) || ' Years ' || trunc(months_between(lease.lease_end_date,(trunc(lease.lease_start_date,'YY'))) - (trunc(months_between(lease.lease_end_date,(trunc(lease.lease_start_date,'YY'))) / 12) * 12)) || ' Months' ||' '|| ( trunc(lease.lease_end_date)- add_months((trunc(lease.lease_start_date,'YY')), trunc(months_between(lease.lease_end_date,(trunc(lease.lease_start_date,'YY')))))) || ' Days '
from dual
```

this is my query but my output is showing as 0 years 11 months 30 Days but i want 1 year 0 months 0 days

Comment: What are your `lease_start_date` and `lease_end_date`?  What is the logic you want to implement (there are many different ways to count months, for example, some more standard than others, which would give different answers-- if the logic you posted isn't what you actually want, you'd need to describe what you want in words).

Comment: Add some line breaks to make your code so much easier to read.

Comment: Sample table data and the expected result would make things clearer. [mcve]

Comment: I don't think you are allowing for the fact that different months have different numbers of days in the month.  And Feb has a different number of days every 4 years.   depending on the actual dates, the output you got could be perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT lease_start_date,
       lease_end_date,
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM year_months) || ' years '
       || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM year_months) || ' months '
       || EXTRACT(DAY FROM day_time) || ' days '
       || EXTRACT(HOUR FROM day_time) || ' hours '
       || EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM day_time) || ' minutes '
       || EXTRACT(SECOND FROM day_time) || ' seconds' AS difference
FROM   (
  SELECT lease_start_date,
         lease_end_date,
         (lease_end_date - lease_start_date) YEAR TO MONTH AS year_months,
         (lease_end_date - ADD_MONTHS(lease_start_date, TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(lease_end_date, lease_start_date)))) DAY TO SECOND AS day_time
  FROM   lease
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE lease (lease_start_date, lease_end_date) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-02-29', DATE '2021-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-29', DATE '2021-02-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-28', DATE '2021-02-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-01', DATE '2020-02-01' + INTERVAL '12:34:56' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | LEASE_START_DATE | LEASE_END_DATE | DIFFERENCE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2020-02-29 00:00:00 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 1 years 0 months 1 days 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds |
> | 2020-02-29 00:00:00 | 2021-02-28 00:00:00 | 1 years 0 months 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds |
> | 2020-02-28 00:00:00 | 2021-02-28 00:00:00 | 1 years 0 months 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds |
> | 2020-02-01 00:00:00 | 2020-02-01 12:34:56 | 0 years 0 months 0 days 12 hours 34 minutes 56 seconds |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c44a90d305a128ca21571f5d6474392)*

Comment: Thank you soo much, your answer is perfect